# How to clone Gists with their real names and not uuid?

Tags: github, git-clone, gist

When cloning a Github Gist, a local repository named after the gist uuid is created, and this repository contains the gist file:

```
+---myLocalRepo
    |
    \---uuid
        |
        \---file.md
```

Is there a way to skip the uuid and clone directly the gist (file.md)?

It would be easier to find and edit local files when working with many gists.

Comment: `git clone <gist-link> <your-name-of-choice>`

Comment: that simple.... thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

`git clone <gist-link> <dir-name>` will place the gist in 'dir-name'